# How to distribute task among few programmers?

Tags: architecture, project-management

In a project, how do you guy assign task among programmers?

Do you distribute the task by use-case basis, or by class basis? Which one do you think is the most efficient?

I plan to assign task by class basis. I can come up with architectural design and give them interface for them to implement.

Comment: This should probably be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about project management, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice against doing it on per class basis unless you are working on a very short project.
You need to think ahead and plan for the changes which will need to be done in the future.
If you have people who only know one particular class well you are prone to them being unavailable at the moment you need them most (e.g. ill, on holiday etc),
And your other team members will not be able to help as they don't know their code.

Use-case basis work better and it really helps to make people do peer code reviews to cross-train them in each other code.